# Secure Spring Boot app with custom scopes/roles

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

In my Jersey app I’ve used `@RolesAllowed("my-scope-or-role-name")` together with an implementation of how to read scopes from a request to ensure authorization. E.g. when HTTP header `my-role-header` had the value `my-scope-or-role-name` I was processing the request.

```
@RolesAllowed("my-scope-or-role-name")
public ResponseEntity<Object> post(@RequestBody final String plainText) {
 // process request
}
```

As the service was behind a proxy, only this proxy could set the value of `my-header`, depending on the access token it got.

What is the idiomatic way to resolve this problem in Spring Boot? I also read about using `@Secured` annotation… But the `@RolesAllowed()` seems to be pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: NOT an expert.

The preferred way seems to be by using the `@PreAuthorize` annotation.

This thing accepts SpEL expressions, which then allows you (assuming all the security and oauth2 stuff has been configured correctly - for example global method level security needs to be enabled) to do interesting things like:

```
@PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('read') and hasAuthority('USER')")
```

I would (humbly) also suggest that your REST endpoints be thin wrappers around service classes (that then do the actual work). AND that the security annotations then be pushed down into those service classes (or their interfaces - apparently you can annotate the interface and it still works).

That should be more secure since nothing can then get to the "job" code without proper security clearance.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but as it's not yet been "answered", but here goes.

As is often the case with Spring the answer is actually more complicated than it seems, and there is more than one way to do this. (By the way, there is a fair amount of reading material on this. See https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/20/spring-preauthorize and https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/spring-security for a more in-depth discussion on this topic.)

Method annotation or method security is what you're trying to do with `@PreAuthorize`, which is one of three annotations supported by Spring Security. OP mentioned `@RolesAllowed`, and `@Secured` is the more Spring-specific third annotation. As has been mentioned, the ability to use SPeL expressions is an advantage of using `@PreAuthorize`, but not the primary reason people use it. I think it is a matter of opinion whether you use one versus another annotation, but they're supposed to work the same, provided you've annotated your application to support them, namely with `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)` depending on what support you need.

In general, method annotation works fine. You just need to be aware that the method annotation will only work if you've enabled it with the flags I've just indicated. It also means your security is distributed across your controllers, which means you can view how your controllers/services are secured simply by looking at them. It does also mean, however, that authorization happens later in the Spring call sequence, so at least in theory access denials take just a tiny bit longer.

The alternative is using HttpSecurity configuration via `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. The advantage I see here is you have all your security in one place, and you still get to use SPeL by using the `.access()` chain method. Because Spring handles security at this level much sooner your access denials will, in theory, happen faster. How much faster I couldn't say, maybe it doesn't matter, but sooner anyway if that matters to you. Where this doesn't work is if you have a controller that calls multiple `@Service` components depending on your access. In this scenario you have to use method security because authorization needs to happen right before the service method is called. Admittedly not the best design, but I could see a use case for this. Basically, if security is not determined or determinable by URI, then you have to rely on method security via these annotations.

I don't know if this answers the question, but hopefully it helps someone.